# explicit lock vs implicit lock implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

two example scenarios:

**first:**

```
public synchronized void foo1(){
              .....
}

public void foo2(){
              .....
}
```

and the **threads** loop is:

```
 public void run() {
        while (true) {
           foo1();
           foo2();
        }
    }
```

if i run 10 threads, and one of these acquire lock inside `foo1()` other threads which want to execute `foo1` will wait outside `foo1()` or they can loop and execute code inside `foo2`?

**second:**

```
public void foo1(){
      lock.lock();
      ....
      lock.unlock();
}

public void foo2(){

}
```

and the **threads** loop is:

```
 public void run() {
        while (true) {
           foo1();
           foo2();
        }
    }
```

if i run 10 threads, and one of these acquire lock inside `foo1()` , in this case  threads which want to execute `foo1` are not blocked outside `foo1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if i run 10 threads, and one of these acquire lock inside foo1() other threads which want to execute foo1 will wait outside foo1() or they can loop and execute code inside foo2?

Assuming they're being called on the same object, they'll all queue up when they need to execute `foo1()`. Any that have already *finished* `foo1()` for that iteration can execute `foo2()`... but then will queue up again on the next iteration when they need to execute `foo1()`.

> if i run 10 threads, and one of these acquire lock inside foo1() , in this case threads which want to execute foo1 are not blocked outside foo1?

Well they're not blocked *outside* `foo1()`, but they'll be blocked *inside* `foo1()`.

The only difference you might see between your examples is in terms of the stack trace. Fundamentally in both cases, executing the main chunk of `foo1()` requires the thread to own the lock.

(Note that your `unlock` call should be in a `finally` block.)

Comment: So, are there no differences between syncronized and lock ?

Comment: @OiRc: There certainly *are* differences, but it depends on what lock type you're using, and your exact requirements. For the simple case of "several threads trying to acquire a lock" they're broadly equivalent... but there's a lot more to it than that.

Comment: is there any suggestion to use to prevent threads being block inside foo1? in terms to free them and continuing to loop?

Comment: @OiRc: Um, don't use a lock? Use `tryLock` if you want to attempt to acquire the lock, but continue on a different path otherwise? You haven't really given enough context to help you - you should create a new question (rather than asking new questions in comments) with details of what you're trying to achieve.